# How can i get a specific item of a Selection field. Odoo 8

Tags: field, selection, onchange, odoo-8, depends

I need help in something what i want to achieve in Odoo 8.
I have 2 selection. A and B. Depending on the value chosen in the selection A i need to show a specific value in the selection B. A piece of code for more clarify:

```
selection_A = fields.Selection([('fruit', 'Fruit'),
                                 ('branch', 'Branch'),
                                 ('root','Root')],
                                'Tree', required=True)

selection_B = fields.Selection([('deep', 'Deep'),
                                 ('large', 'Large'),
                                 ('orange','Orange')],
                                'Feature', required=True)
```

So, when the fruit is selected in selection_A i need to show in the selection_B 'Orange' as result.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function with @api.onchange('selection_A'). And it will get called when you change the value of selection_A. Then you can write the required value to selection_B.

```
@api.onchange('selection_A')
def compute_selection_B(self):
    if self.selection_A == 'fruit':
        self.selection_B = 'orange'
```